# How to change the background color in this example

Tags: python, background, tkinter

I have been playing around with this example code just trying different things.  I think Bryan Oakley originally wrote this. Given this example code how can I change the gray area, what I believe is the window background, to black? It looks to me that the window is using the standard window color of gray. I have changed every Frame in an attempt to figure out each area and how they are displayed. I have also added the root background tag with no luck. This is driving me a little nuts.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *


class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()


class Page1(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        newframe = tk.Frame(self, width=780, height=540, background="red")
        newframe.place(anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)

class Page2(Page):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        newframe = tk.Frame(self, width=780, height=540, background="blue")
        newframe.place(anchor="c", relx=.5, rely=.5)


class MainView(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        p1 = Page1(self)
        p2 = Page2(self)

        buttonframe = tk.Frame(self, bg='green')
        container = tk.Frame(self, bg='yellow')
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        p1.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        p2.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.b1 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 1", command=lambda: p1.lift())
        self.b1.pack(side="left")
        self.b2 = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Page 2", command=lambda: p2.lift())
        self.b2.pack(side="left")

        p1.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    main = MainView(root)
    root.configure(bg='black')
    main.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("800x600")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have also tried     main.configure(bg='black')

Comment: this is the minimum code you can come up with to reproduce? ... why not start with a single frame?

Comment: Yes. It is a paging example so the minimum pages you can have and still show the functionality is two.  The having more than one page and being able to lift each one is important to the question since the gray area appears to be coming from something other than the root.background.   I don't think there is anything else that can have a bg applied to it so the gray area  has me scratching my head.

Comment: Very embarrassing! That's my code, and there's a bug -- classes that inherit from `Page` need to call the `Page` constructor...

Comment: I think just solved it Bryan. I will post what I did....

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why this works but here is what I did. Inside the MainView change the two p1, p2 code to the following.

```
    p1 = Page1(self, bg='black')
    p2 = Page2(self, bg='black')
```